# VB.NET - WebBrowser doesn't show html elements created by javascript in the html source code

Tags: javascript, vb.net, browser, code-injection

I am having a difficulty handling some HTML Elements that are only shown after some javascript injection.

To be more specific, the html page that loads in my WebBrowser Class has an image. When I programmatically click on it, it creates some  tags, which have text boxes and buttons on them.

The problem is that these  tags cannot be parsed, since they are created in javascript and hence not shown in the page source. I can only see them in Firefox browser, when I inspect the javascript elements, but they are all greyed-out , like hidden.

I want to change the values of the textfields and click on the button within the javascript-generated  tags.

I already have checked the HtmlElementCollection and (as stated above) they're nowhere to be found.

Any ideas or help?

Ps. what if i get the coordinates by some way and then move programmatically the mouse there? Though, that's a solution i would not prefer..

Answer (score 1):

1. Dynamically generated elements/contents are not available in html source.
2. you can attach events to dynamically generated html melements by [jquery **on**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

---

```
<body>
<p>Click me!</p>
<script>
    var count = 0;
    $("body").on("click", "p", function(){
      $(this).after("<p>Another paragraph! "+(++count)+"</p>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The issue is that i have to do it inside my vb.net project, using the WebBrowser class.